# HTML ampersand character codes not loaded in form text box -PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, yii, special-characters

How can I parse `&amp;` (from mysql database) to & in html form text box field.

In database the data "a & b" save as `a &amp; b` and when i try to update the data, it load as  "`a &amp; b`" in text box.

Is there any inbuilt function in Yii?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Comment: use htmlentities ( http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
echo html_entity_decode('a &amp; b');
```